# Python Statsmodels: OLS regressor not predicting

Tags: python, regression, statsmodels

I wrote the following piece of code but I just cannot get the 'predict' method to work:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels.formula.api import ols
ols_model = ols('Consumption ~ Disposable_Income', df).fit()
```

My 'df' is a pandas dataframe with column headings 'Consumption' and 'Disposable_Income'. When I run, for example,

```
ols_model.predict([1000.0])
```

I get: "TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str"

When I run, for example,

```
ols_model.predict(df['Disposable_Income'].values)
```

I get: "IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices"

I'm very confused because I thought these two formats are precisely what the documentation says - put in an array of values for the x variable. How exactly am I supposed to use the 'predict' method?

This is how my df look:
[image]

Comment: Could you post df.head()?

Comment: @WoodChopper ok, see edited post

Comment: `~` is different operator in pandas from R.

Comment: Please provide full tracebacks or at least the last few lines, so we see where the exception has been raised. The first exception might be a bug in patsy for different kinds of integers that has already been fixed, but I don't know if it released yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you work with the formulas in the model, the formula information will also be used in the interpretation of the exog in `predict`.

I think you need to use a dataframe or a dictionary with the correct name of the explanatory variable(s).

`ols_model.predict({'Disposable_Income':[1000.0]})`

or something like

```
df_predict = pd.DataFrame([[1000.0]], columns=['Disposable_Income'])
ols_model.predict(df_predict)
```

Another option is to avoid formula handling in predict if the full design matrix for prediction, including constant, is available

AFAIR, this should also work:

`ols_model.predict([[1, 1000.0]], transform=False)`

Comment: You are right - it works! I totally didn't know that I need to use a dictionary syntax. Thanks for teaching me something new

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best approach, but after lots and lots of fiddling around, I got this code to work (seems abit clumsy and inefficient):

Say I want to predict the value at X=10 and X=1000:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels.formula.api import ols
ols_model = ols('Consumption ~ Disposable_Income', df).fit()
regressor = ols('Consumption ~ Disposable_Income', df)
regressor.predict(ols_model.params, exog=[[1,10],[1,1000]])
```