# Applying an OLS Model to a Different DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, regression, statsmodels

I have created an OLS model of 3-digit zip code data:

```
x = nsaid_df[['Segment', 'FTE_A', 'FTE_B', 'FTE_C', 'inc100k']]
y = nsaid_df['Sales']
model = sm.OLS(y, x, missing='drop').fit()
model.summary()
```

The model makes a link between demographic data (at the 3-digit zip code level) and sales of a product. I'd now like to use the model to predict sales at a 5 digit zip code level. I have a DataFrame containing the exact same series as the 3-Digit model, but for each 5 digit zip code. I would have thought I could simply write:

```
predict5 = model.predict(alx5)
```

This gives a somewhat cryptic error message:

"shapes (33678,15) and (5,) not aligned: 15 (dim 1) != 5 (dim 0)"

My question is, **how do I use my model to predict values in a dataframe which is different from the one used to fit the original model**?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33476897/python-statsmodels-ols-regressor-not-predicting/33477147#33477147

Comment: @WoodChopper - different error

Answer (score 0):

Looks to be the same as this question [predicting-out-future-values-using-ols-regression-python-statsmodels-pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30178254/predicting-out-future-values-using-ols-regression-python-statsmodels-pandas)

So the answer is:

```
new_x = alx5[['Segment', 'FTE_A', 'FTE_B', 'FTE_C', 'inc100k']]
alx5.loc[:, 'NSAID'] = model.predict(new_x)
```

Comment: Cool if it resolved your question you can accept your own question and close it.